# Error: Can't resolve 'swiper_angular' swiper in angular 11

Tags: angular, swiper.js

I have the following error for using `swiper` in the project.

```
Error: ./node_modules/swiper/angular/swiper_angular.ngfactory.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'swiper_angular' in 'D:\Source\PharmacySite\pharmacySite4\PharmacySite\fronend\node_modules\swiper\angular'
```

in app.module.ts inported import `{ SwiperModule } from 'swiper/angular';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please try below npm package? This may solve your problem.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-swiper-wrapper

Comment: I want use from this: 
`https://codesandbox.io/s/swiper-angular-navigation-forked-vm86u?file=/package.json:202-204`

Comment: @Mojtaba Nava, you can use "ngx-swiper-wrapper", but it will increase the size of your project. You can use the original "swiper" library and add some configuration as "Devner" said in another answer.

Answer (score 4):

In **tsconfig.json** file, add the entry for **swiper_angular** as shown in the following and restart your server:

```
"compilerOptions": {
  "paths": {
    "swiper_angular": ["node_modules/swiper/angular"]
  }
}
```

Comment: Awesome!!! Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score -1):

In the tsconfig.json add Path object inside compilerOptions  and re-run your app

```
  "compilerOptions": {
      "paths": {
        "swiper_angular": ["node_modules/swiper/angular"]
      }
    }
```

Comment: in the tsconfig.json add Path object inside compilerOptions  and re-run your app @Mojtaba Nava

Comment: What does this add to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70702229/10871073), posted over a year ago? In fact, how is it significantly different from that answer?